# can use .append() but not .style of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reference

I am storing a reference to an object I created, and calling .append() on i works fine, though if I try doing a style change it won't allow me...

The error I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Any ideas?

```
//add this slide's wrapper to module
self.node = $("<div id='module_"+self.moduleId+"-slide_"+self.currentSlide+"' class='slide fade'></div>").appendTo("div#module_"+self.moduleId);

//add the contents of the slide to its wrapper div
self.node.append( self.slides[self.currentSlide-1].html )

//Hack to force webKit to repaint (to have style fade applied) before the show() event.
self.node.style.display='none';
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? Your self.node.append isn't terminated.

Comment: or self.node[0] to access the underlying object

Comment: why @Adrift does not answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to do this:

```
    self.node = $("<div id='module_"+self.moduleId+"-slide_"+self.currentSlide+"' class='slide fade'></div>").appendTo("div#module_"+self.moduleId);

    self.node.append( self.slides[self.currentSlide-1].html );
    self.node.hide();
    //or
    self.node.css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 1):

This line gives you a reference to a jQuery object:

```
self.node = $("<div id='module_"+self.moduleId+"-slide_"+self.currentSlide+"' class='slide fade'></div>").appendTo("div#module_"+self.moduleId);
```

You are referencing the jQuery object, when it looks like you [need the actual DOM element](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/), which is accessed via

```
self.node[0]
```

So your code would then read:

```
self.node[0].style.display='none';
```